# Thermal fluctuations in metals

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, metals, quantum-statistics

My professor said that the $k_BT$ displacement in the energy levels of the band electrons is due to the space-thermal displacement of the potential of the ion host. I think that this displacement is due to the thermal fluctuations of the electromagnetic field coupled to the electron charge.

Who is right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you perform an optical absorption measurement using a laser, your field will have no thermal fluctuations, but you will still observe a slight lowering (in energy) of the onset of absorption (band gap). So unless I don't understand what you are suggesting (very possible), then he is correct.

Comment: @garyp,"If you perform an optical absorption measurement using a laser, your field will have no thermal fluctuations,..." You can give me some text about that.I think that, bacause thermal fluctuations in the electrons band, we need to have some Electromagnetic fluctuation due to the charge coupling.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are saying.  Electronic states (actually, coupled EM - electronic states) are slightly broadened as a result of coupling to the EM field, but the size of this broadening is much less than $kT$.  Effects on the order of $kT$ can't be due to this mechanism.

Comment: oO, but is a thermal equilibrium !

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.  If you use a laser source, the light is not in thermal equilibrium with the object.

Comment: ...but exist a thermal background that don't interfere with the laser beam ? The laser beam is not a full configuration of the electromagnetic field. The thermal fluctuations is still there. We have another sources of light in the environment of the laser device. This light emitted by the other sources don't escape of the device.